# How to control NPC animation from GUI button click (Unreal)

Tags: unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5

I have a number of animation sequences connected to an ENUM Blend Pose node. I can manually switch this enum value in the Anim Preview panel.

Now I wish to control this enum value from a bunch of buttons added to a User Widget. The widget is instantiated within the Level BP.

When I edit the onClick events on the buttons, I do not know how to get a reference to my enum variable (which I have exposed as Public in the Anim Blueprint's settings).

Essentially, each button is designed to change this variable to a unique value, which then should cause the appropriate animation to play within the Blend Pose.

How do I let the Widget have access to that variable? Or vice versa, how could I create a variable on the blueprint that can be used to set the Enum value on the Blend Pose?

Please note that I am using the visual blueprint editor, not C++ at this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am coming from a 100% C++ background, so I may have some options on my mind that are not entirely working in BP, but we'll get to that.

1. I would not use the level blueprint at all for anything. Instead use your GameMode or GameState for spawning the UserWiget. The GameMode and GameState are accessible via the GetGameMode node. Keep in mind that in multiplayer scenarios, only the GameState is available to all while the GameMode can only be accessed by the host or dedicated server, but that is probably irrelevant for you.
2. After spawning the widget assign it to a public variable of its type, so you can get it from the outside.
3. In your actor (not animation blueprint) you can access the GameMode easily using the [GetGameMode](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.1/en-US/BlueprintAPI/Game/GetGameMode/) node. You have to cast it to your specific GameMode to get to the variable of the widget. For the GameState use [GetGameState](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.1/en-US/BlueprintAPI/Game/GetGameState/).
4. Now you have multiple options to connect everything together. You could for example pass your actor to the UI and store it as a variable there. The UI can then simply call a custom function like "SetAnimationState" that you create on the actor for each button. Your actor can pass the enum value down to the animation blueprint. Using your skeletal meshes [GetAnimInstance](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/BlueprintAPI/Components/SkeletalMesh/GetAnimInstance/) node.

This is one simple way I can think of. You could also work with an [event dispatcher](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.1/en-US/event-dispatchers-in-unreal-engine/) that broadcasts whenever a button is pressed and your actor is subscribed to it to get notified.

I hope any of this helps.

Comment: I'm liking the direction you're taking me in. Can you elaborate on "pass your actor to the UI"? If the actor has a reference to GameState, how does the Widget (that's instantiated by the GameState) get access to the Actor instance? Also - when you speak of the "Actor" I have a `CR_Mannequin_Body (Instance)` - is that the actor? How do I give it a blueprint?

Comment: Sorry for that last brain fart. I do know how to convert an actor to a BP. My earlier question still holds though.

Comment: The actor gets the widget and then assigns itself either to a public variable or calls a function with a parameter of its own type where it can use the output of the "self" node to pass itself over to the UI as a reference. This function does not exist, yet, you have to create it. The widget has a blueprint and the actor has a blueprint, you just have to connect them both in a way.

Comment: Thanks! I wonder if all this wouldn't be more obvious if I were actually coding in C++ where the OOP principles of encapsulation are more self-evident. I'm just worried there's a lot of boilerplate stuff I'd have to do that the blueprint system takes care of for you. Let me try out what you suggest!

Comment: As I stated in my answer: I work mainly in C++, so my view is heavily biased. I believe that blueprints are not easier to use than C++ most of the time, if you are familiar with the language. Unreal does a lot for you and if you want I can drop my take on an implementation as an edit into my answer.

Comment: Well I'm so close I can taste it. I created a function on the Actor Blueprinbt `SetAnimFromEnum()` that takes the ENUM value as input and sets the corresponding variable on the Animation blueprint. Then on initialization, the Anim Blueprint gets a refernce to the Widget and then calls a function I created on the widget that gives the widget a reference to the Anim blueprint! So all that's left is onClick to grab that reference (which I store in a variable on the Widget BP) and call the SetAnimFromEnum function but it's not coming up in the Node selector!

Comment: So, you have `SetAnimFromEnum()` in your Actor Blueprint, but you pass the Animation Blueprint to the `UserWidget`? This won't give you the Widget access to the method that is on the actor, because you passed the wrong actor. At least that's what I read from your text. You should just pass the reference of the Actor with the Skeletal Mesh to the Widget instead.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @MaxPlay's answer, here's my final (possibly sub-optimal) solution with images for posterity. I'll probably stumble upon this answer in a few years like I do with some of my other SO posts from years ago ;)

First, the Anim BP on my Actor (note that this is not the player's pawn but just another mesh in the world) which just sets up the Blend Poses, using an Enum.

[image: Animation Blueprint]

It's really vitally important here to make sure the variable that holds the Enum is made public. You do that by clicking the eye icon next to the variable name. If you don't do this, no external class (blueprint) gets to read or set the value of that variable.

This is a screen grab of the variables portion of the Anim BP's properties panel.

[image: Animation Blueprint's public variables]

And here's that Enum, which you can create as a blueprint. I've used it to have a nice textual reference that has semantic meaning. Also makes it easier to link to the buttons later.

[image: Enumeration Blueprint]

Now we get into the heart of the matter - the Actor Blueprint. I just wrapped this blueprint around my Skeletal Mesh Asset by selecting it in the viewport and then using the Blueprint menu to convert it.

In the image below you can see the Details panel of that Actor Blueprint, showing how it composes the Anim BP

[image: Actor BP Anim BP properties]

Next is the magic step!

I created a function on the Actor Blueprint that other blueprints can call with 1 parameter - the ENUM that I defined earlier. The goal of this function is as a public setter on the Anim BP's public variable. I wasn't able to expose this public variable outside the hierarchy, so this gets around that visibility issue by delegating the responsibility for setting the Anim BP's variable to its Actor BP.

Since the Actor Blueprint has a reference internally to its Skeletal Mesh's currently assigned animation blueprint, and that Anim BP's variable has been made public, it gets to set it directly.

The goal is to pass a reference to this Actor BP to the Widget so the Widget's buttons can call this method (function) at a later time.

[image: Anim BP Function]

Over on the Widget side, I'm exposing a variable, cast as that specific animation blueprint (so that the Widget knows about the `SetAnimFromEnum` method). I'll be setting that variable in a moment.

[image: Widget Properties - Actor BP as a variable]

Before I do, here's how the Widget Blueprint is set up - very simply, each button calls the same `SetAnimFromEnum()` method and just passes a different value from the enum.

If you had a million buttons, this would not be efficient and you might want to invest in a bit more complex blueprinting (I'm not yet at that level) - ideas here are to somehow parse the name / label of the button and derive the appropriate enum from it, or revert to an integer-based Blend Pose node and add a property to each button, etc.

[image: Widget Blueprint - calling function on Actor BP]

And finally, the glue that holds it all together: the Actor Blueprint that instantiates the widget. This is the part I don't like in my solution - in my mind, the widget shouldn't be so tightly coupled (composed) with the Actor BP. But I would have had to jump through more hoops if using the Global GameMode or GameState Blueprints, and this is just a proof-of-concept so I'm keeping it simple, if slightly messy.

The Animation Blueprint below shows me instantiating the Widget and using the return value to both add it to the Viewport, as well as then accessing the widget's public variable designed to hold a reference to this Actor Blueprint and setting it. That creates the link between these two blueprints allowing the Widget to then call a method on the Actor.

[image: Animation Blueprint showing widget instantiation]

Comment: One of the challenges with this approach is when it comes to Metahumans and actual dialogue. As opposed to just having manny wave his arms, I'm trying to get a Metahuman to move and talk - so there's now a body animation, a face animation and an audio track that all must be synchronized. Level Sequences are a much better way to assemble and tweak these animations, but I don't know how to utilize level sequences in the same programmatic way that I'm scripting just skeletal animations here. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77490407/npc-blending-animation-sequences-programmatically