# NPC - Blending animation sequences programmatically

Tags: unreal-engine5, metahuman

in my project I have an NPC character dialogue that consists of a number of pre-scripted Metahuman animation sequences (face + body + audio) that can be played back in random order depending on user choices. There are no camera cuts or camera animation in-between sequences - it must all feel like one continuous dialogue.

Queueing up a level sequence and playing it is pretty easy. What's got me stumped is how to have level sequences BLEND seamlessly into one another with no camera cuts to hide the abrupt transition.

The NPC is a Metahuman, thus I think I need a level sequence in order to be able to combine and synchronize the Face, Body and Audio tracks. As far as I know an Animation Montage can only work on one skeleton at a time and doesn't hold audio, so I think the level sequence is the only way to go.

Is it possible to programmatically blend two level sequences that share the same skeletal meshes, and if so what is the best way to set this up?